# Trying get titles from multiple pages in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all blog titles from every page on a blog but so far am only able to produce output from the last page on that blog

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://www.madame-love.com'

n = 10
for i in range(2, n+1):
    html = urlopen(base_url + "/page/%d" % i)
    page = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

for titles in page.findAll('h2'):
    print(titles.string)
```

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: python 3 does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will give you all the titles across different pages:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://www.madame-love.com/page/{}/'
for link in [base_url.format(page) for page in range(1,5)]:  #just input the highest page number in place of 5
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    for titles in soup.select('h2.entry-title a'):
        print(titles.text)
```